# Kubernetes ImagePullBackOff with Private Registry on Docker Hub

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, dockerhub

I have a private Docker Hub registry with a (rather large) image in it that I control.

I also have a Helm deployment chart that specifies an `imagePullSecret`, after having followed the instructions here https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/.

No matter what I do, though, when installing the Helm chart, I always end up with the following (taken from `kubectl describe pod <pod-id>`):

```
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                  From               Message
  ----     ------     ----                 ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  26m                  default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/<release>-69584657b7-vkps6 to <node>
  Warning  Failed     6m28s (x3 over 20m)  kubelet            Failed to pull image "<registry-username>/<image>:latest": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image "docker.io/<registry-username>/<image>:latest": failed to copy: httpReadSeeker: failed open: server message: invalid_token: authorization failed
  Warning  Failed     6m28s (x3 over 20m)  kubelet            Error: ErrImagePull
  Normal   BackOff    5m50s (x5 over 20m)  kubelet            Back-off pulling image "<registry-username>/<image>:latest"
  Warning  Failed     5m50s (x5 over 20m)  kubelet            Error: ImagePullBackOff
  Normal   Pulling    5m39s (x4 over 26m)  kubelet            Pulling image "<registry-username>/<image>:latest"
```

I have looked high and low on the internet for answers pertaining to this `invalid_token` output, but have yet to find anything concrete.

I have verified that I can run `docker pull` manually with the image in question both on the K8s node as well as other boxes. It works just fine.

I have tried using `docker.io` as the repository URI, as well as (the recommended) `https://index.docker.io/v1/`.

I have tried using my own Docker Hub password as well as a generated Personal Access Token (I can actually see in Docker Hub that the PAT was, in fact, used, despite the pull failing).

I've examined the secrets via `kubectl` to verify they're of the expected format and contain the correct data (username, password/token, etc.). They're all fine and match what I'd get when I run `docker login` on the command line.

I have used this node to deploy other releases via Helm and they have all worked fine (although at least one has been from a different registry).

I am relatively new to K8s and Helm, but I've used Docker for a long while now and I'm at a loss as to this `invalid_token` issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

**UPDATE**

Here's the (sanitized) output of `helm template`:

```
---
# Source: <deployment>/templates/deployment.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: release-name-<deployment>
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: <deployment>-0.1.0
    app.kubernetes.io/name: <deployment>
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: release-name
    app.kubernetes.io/version: "1.16.0"
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: <deployment>
      app.kubernetes.io/instance: release-name
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/name: <deployment>
        app.kubernetes.io/instance: release-name
    spec:
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: regcred-docker-pat
      securityContext:
        {}
      containers:
        - name: <deployment>
          securityContext:
            {}
          image: "<registry-username>/<image>:latest"
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          resources:
            {}
```

I've also confirmed that any secrets I have tried are, in fact, in the same namespace as the pod (in this case, the `default` namespace).

Comment: Your summary of your approach is logical. One thing that's missing is the configuration that's being applied to the cluster by Helm. Can you include a synopsis of the Deployment that's being generated by Helm? I don't use Helm often but I think `helm template` should give you the configs that are being applied.

Comment: I'll amend my question to include it, but I did use that command to check it's using the secret it should be. Or at least I think it is.

Comment: That looks good. Have you tried `kubectl apply`'ing that Deployment directly?

Comment: I've only done `helm install ...`  ...should I install it, wait for it to fail, and the run `apply`? Or is there a different ordering to try?

Comment: What's `kubectl install`?

Comment: Apologies. I meant `helm install`. Corrected that in my comment.

Comment: If you have the `foo.yaml`, you can `kubectl delete --filename=/path/to/foo.yaml` and then `kubectl apply --filename=/path/to/foo.yaml` add `--namespace=${NAMESPACE}` if you're using.

Comment: Running `delete` gives me `error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 5: did not find expected node content` ...I could post the entire deployment YAML, if that would help. I haven't really edit the starting deployment template all that much.

Comment: Ah, my bad... Your Helm template must be replacing values like `release-name-<deployment>`. I thought that was you redacting content.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood? I was using the deployment template, not a rendered version or anything. The `helm template` output does have redacted content, but the `release-name-` part is actually unedited from `helm template`, while the `<deployment>` part is my redaction.

Comment: You need to use the rendered version. You're manually applying the config to the cluster. I'm trying to eliminate the possibility that Helm's borking the step. Admittedly it's unlikely but... Another possibility is that the secret is incorrect. Is everything in the same namespace?

Comment: All is in the default namespace, yes. The rendered version of the template contains stuff like `release-name`, but I'm pretty sure that's replaced when `helm install` is run, so I don't know if using the output of `helm template` will help.

Comment: Follow the steps here: Pull an Image from a Private Registry https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/

Comment: @jmvcollaborator If you'll look in my original post, you'll see I already did that, with no luck.

Comment: For some reason, this just magically started working this morning when I turned on the node. I changed absolutely nothing.  Going to keep an eye on it.

Answer (score -1):

Is the `imagepullsecret` created by the helm chart?
Is the `imagepullsecret` available when the deployment is created?
Do you apply the deployment before the imagepullsecret is available?

I remember the order matters when applying the imagepullsecret; the kube-api does not retry pulling after failure because of authentication.

Comment: No, the secret was created by `kubectl` before I ran `helm install`.